# Arraylist index in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, indexing

I have an `ArrayList` and I want to give index as big integer value (Customer ID)

ex:

```
limitAmountTotal[CUSTOMERID] = amount;
```

where CUSTOMERID = 1000000

But I am getting an error

> arraylist is out of range

Is there any way I can handle this in C#?

in PHP we can do this like this

```
$limitAmountTotal[$CUSTOMERID] = $amount;
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it why would you want to use ArrayList in this case? Isn't dictionary a better solution for this... ?

Comment: arraylist inital capability is zero (from 3.5 and above). see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565000/what-is-the-initial-size-of-arraylist-in-c

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs old days that C# doesn't have _Generics_. Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: I suggest to use `List<T>` as @SonerGönül said before or simple `Array`... but `Array` may be inapropriate for this if it should dynamically change its size.

Comment: @SonerGönül just for my understanding, what's wrong with a `Dictionary` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `ArrayList` behaves like an array. You want [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
Dictionary<int, int> limitAmountTotal  = new Dictionary<int, int>();
limitAmountTotal[10000] = 30;
```

Comment: Because you want to dereference using a key, not an index.

Comment: Why don't use single list/array for this? He want some big integer (long) as index not some special key or I am missing something here.

Comment: Wouldn't an array consume way to much memory?

Comment: Are you serious...? - http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-dictionary-test how did you get 13.7k reputation points I don't know...

Comment: @rosko: no need to be insulting. First, your link does not address memory usage, only speed. Second I reckon the asker might not have 1,000,000 items in his array. If you would use an array and want to dereference the 1,000,000th object, you will have allocated a million unused objects. In a `Dictionary` only used objects are allocated.

Comment: Maybe at some point you are right but simplest solutions are most of the time the best.

Comment: @rosko I don't see how a single list/array is simpler. I agree with Bart, so  I'll be upvoting his answer.

Comment: @rosko, An array is not a solution.  With only the 1,000,000 items as would be required per the question, you would consume 3.9 MB of memory, not huge, but enough to be matter.  Unless the set is dense, there is no reason not to use a dictionary.

Comment: I did some measurement of my own and I edited my answer - it may be not 100% correct but I wanted to check whether I was wrong or not. I am sorry that I over-reacted - it was probably due to lack of my morning coffee but anyway the one who asked a question didn't even care to come here and thank you. No offence once again, have a good day!

Answer (score -2):

Use `List<T>` or simple `Array` (array is optional but not recommended for this!).

If your `amount` is some monetary value then you can try using:

```
decimal[] arr = new decimal[arraySize];
```

or:

```
List<decimal> list = new List<decimal>();
```

If not change `decimal` to whatever data type you like: `int`, `long` and etc.

Edit:

Some performance and memory tests:

```
All collections are type of `int`
Maximum collection size: 1000000
Random generated index used for value lookup: 354497

Array populating time elapsed: 00:00:00.0063499
Array lookup time elapsed: 00:00:00.0000004
Size: 4000028 bytes
==============
List populating time elapsed: 00:00:00.0184629
List lookup time elapsed: 00:00:00.0000004
Size: 4194509 bytes
==============
Dictionary populating time elapsed: 00:00:00.0593676
Dictionary lookup time elapsed: 00:00:00.0000293
Size: 17001335 bytes
```

Code: https://gist.github.com/rekosko/999e58dc95ba3e4fc678

Comment: To access an array in the way he wants he would first need to initialize an array with length of 1000000 just so he could use it in a way limitAmountTotal[1000000] = amount. Same goes for List<T>. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right but you don't really know if he needs an array that is so large anyway it's just an option to use an array i didn't say it's the way, right?

Comment: It could be even worse, he would maybe need an even larger array ;)

Comment: As I said - the usage of array is just an option.